# Everyone is asking Now is Ethereum still ASIC Resistant?

Tags: go-ethereum, cpp-ethereum, etherscan

According to Bitmain - plus other 3 company in china, that they will lunch Asic Miner Machine for Ethereum this 2nd Quarter 2018.

My question is there any way that ethereum can prevent this to happen?

Is this news true?

How Resistant Ethereum from Asic Miner Machine?

Answer (score 0):

According to the co founder of ethereum - that they will change the fork of ethereum.

Currently Bitmain are selling their Asic Miner for ethereum for 800 dollars and its  pre- order.

In my opinion. Please don't buy it yet. Why? The time it will come to your doorstep or shipped the unit. Ethereum is already change its algorithm which will make your investment useless. You will just have an expensive noisy, heater in your house.